# Get Distinct data with join few tables Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is regarding sequelize ORM and I'm developing node js APIs for meal application.
MealPrice table *(FK : mealId)* is linked to meal table *(PK : Id)* , meal table *(FK : RestaurantId)* is linked to restaurant table *(PK : Id)*. There is no direct join to "restaurant" table from "mealprice" table.
What I need is, if I pass "IsActive = true" statuses to mealPrice table and should get restaurant (distinct list) list. Honestly I do not have much experience on sequelize ORM. This is what I try up to now and it returns mealPrice and meal data.

```
        global.mealpricing.belongsTo(global.meal, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'mealId' });
        global.meal.belongsTo(global.resturant, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'resturantId' });

        global.mealpricing.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: global.meal,
            }],

            where: { isActive: true }
        }).then(meals => {
            res.send(meals);
        });
```

What my concern is how to get JSON distinct list of only restaurant? Please give me a direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get all the restaurant IDs by using an inner join of *mealpricing* with *meal* table
- Find all the restaurants through these IDs, using distinct operator on 'id' column

  ```
  global.mealpricing.findAll({ 
   where: {isActive: true},
   include: {
     model: global.meal,
     attributes: ['resturantId']
   }
  })
  .then(mealPricingDocs => {
    const restaurantIds = mealPricingDocs.map(i => i.meal.restaurantId);
    return global.restaurant.findAll({
     where: { id: { $in: restaurantIds } },
     distinct: 'id'
    });
  })
  .then(restaurants => res.send(restaurants));
  ```

Comment: Wow.... It is working... Thanks... But my concern is, will above query hit to performance, when growing the DB, cause there is "IN" inside the where condition. When we do this with SQL, we not need any kind of "IN" clause and can just do this with INNER JOIN and DISTINCT keywords.